# Movie about a girl who wishes or writes in a book for things to happen to people?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

This movie is probably early 2000’s, something I saw on SyFy or Lifetime.

I have no clue how it starts and can only remember specific scenes. One of them being a scene where a girl is in a bathroom and her friends are outside in her house or something and her teeth or hair start falling out? This could be my brain trying to make something up though.

Another scene is where the main character is in her room and her moms boyfriend or step dad comes in and tries to make advances with her that she denies and she yells “I wish you were dead” or “I wish you would die” and then I believe she stabs him with a pair of scissors?

Throughout the movie she is carrying a small diary around which is what she writes in or wishes to.

The last scene I can remember is of her in a cemetery or something and a priest or man of the church is trying to help her or something but then I believe he also tries to make advances with her and she kills him?

Tthe closest thing it’s somewhat similar to is a movie with Rose Mcgowan that I can’t remember the title of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Devil's Diary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1018820/combined) from 2007 that aired on Lifetime.

> When two friends, Dominique and Ursula, uncover an ancient book in a graveyard one night, they discover that the book has the supernatural power to grant any evil desire written within it. In a series of escalating acts of vengeance, Ursula harms anyone who opposes her. Dominique realizes that the book begins to control her friend with a sense of ultimate power, can Ursula be saved before it's too late?

All the scenes are there, including Ursula's hair and teeth falling out, Dominique's creepy stepfather stabbing himself with a pair of scissors and the scene with the priest in the end. Here's the trailer:

Comment: you’re the best, again! helping me find all of these movies that have been wracking my brain for years! thank you!

Comment: No problem. Not sure what the Mcgowan film is though... Maybe flashbacks of the girls from *Jawbreaker*?

Comment: Devil in the Flesh actually!